# Remove selected items from combo box

Tags: c#

I wish to remove selected item from combo box 
The selected items from combo box are dispayed in a data grid view and i dont wish to reselect the same item from the same combo box .
How can this be done ? , plz help

```
combobox1InHouseStatus.Items.RemoveAt(combobox1InHouseStatus.SelectedIndex);
```

I tried this but it isnt working !!!

Comment: post your attempt please

Comment: Did you tried anything so far?

Comment: not sufficient, how is this combo box being created. does it get bind to a datasource on page load or something

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing, but in my case multiple items could be selected.  Here's the code I used:

```
int x = this.aComboBox.SelectedItems.Count;
while (x >= 1) {
    this.aComboBox.Items.Remove(this.aComboBox.SelectedItems(x - 1));
    x -= 1;
}
```